# WebRTC - how to detect the status of upload/download bandwidth?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, networking, webrtc

For example: Peer 1 is located in Africa ,  Peer 2 is located in UK. Now P1 upload is very low and download is very slow also it get disconnected over and over

In such situation, how do we detect the Peer 1 bandwidth via WebRTC to determine weather is it
3G or 4G or WiFi or Lan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can access to that information using the NetworkInformation interface:

https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/tip/network-api/Overview.html

Peer2 can send the information to Peer1 using the Data Channel.

After that, you can customize the bandwidth using something like this: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/bandwidth.html?audio=30&video=256

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested specifically in whether the machine is from 3G/4G or landline there are services that can detect it based on the ip of the user, [like this](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing).

Assuming such connectivity type, based on the throughput of the uplink/downlink is not consistent (for example if the user is on landline but downloads a file while in your service)